# netty localhost

Tags: client-server, netty

In netty, what is the best way to find the connected client is in localhost?

Note: e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress() gives ip address like 127.0.0.1:5555
but i can not be sure that localhost is set to that ip address.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to handle requests from remote clients? Or do you allow only connections from localhost?

Comment: yes, i need to handle request from remote clients only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this isn't a Netty question.

If you want to determine that the remote address is really remote (i.e. from another host) you can try to look up the `NetworkInterface` using the IP address, and if you get `null`, it is really remote.

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress().getAddress());
if (ni == null) 
    // remote client
```